# iOS - Dependency injection in UIViewController

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, dependency-injection, segue

I am looking for an elegant way to implement DI in view controllers when working with segues.
If i have controller A that eventually loads controller B i would like to unit test this behavior. What would be a good way to implement it?

Answer (score 3):

It would be really helpful if there was a straightforward way for us to use "constructor" injection when using storyboards, but sadly there isn't since the framework is handling VC initialization for us.

Depending on the size and the context of the project in general, you can either go for a full-fledged framework like Typhoon (which is very good in my experience) or try something simpler like using a mediator to handle all segues between VCs.

I've written about the latter method here: http://cocoapatterns.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers/ and here http://cocoapatterns.com/ios-view-controller-transitions-mediator-pattern/

Especially when combined with the State Design pattern, mediator provides a central way for handling injection during segues and also helps with maintenance and extensibility of the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the light-weight [Typhoon](http://www.typhoonframework.org/) dependency injection library. Typhoon works by taking advantage of the Objective-C runtime's message forwarding abilities. You can define one or more 'assemblies' as follows:

- At build-time assemblies return `TyphoonDefinition`s - recipes for assembling components.
- At runtime we use the assembly interface to resolve built components, with their dependencies injected according to the defined rules.

**Example: ApplicationAssembly.swift**

```
public class ApplicationAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    /*
     * These are modules - assemblies collaborate to provie components to this one.  
     * At runtime you can instantiate Typhoon with any assembly that satisfies the 
     * module interface.
     */
    var coreComponents : CoreComponents!
    var themeAssembly : ThemeAssembly!


    public dynamic func weatherReportController() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(WeatherReportViewController.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.useInitializer("initWithWeatherClient:weatherReportDao:cityDao:assembly:") {
                (initializer) in

                initializer.injectParameterWith(self.coreComponents.weatherClient())
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self.coreComponents.weatherReportDao())
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self.coreComponents.cityDao())
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self)

            }
        };
    }

    public dynamic func addCityViewController() -> AnyObject {

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AddCityViewController.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.useInitializer("initWithNibName:bundle:") {
                (initializer) in

                initializer.injectParameterWith("AddCity")
                initializer.injectParameterWith(NSBundle.mainBundle())
            }
            definition.injectProperty("cityDao", with:self.coreComponents.cityDao())
            definition.injectProperty("weatherClient", with:self.coreComponents.weatherClient())
            definition.injectProperty("theme", with:self.themeAssembly.currentTheme())
            definition.injectProperty("rootViewController", with:self.rootViewController())
        }                
    }
}
```

This style of Dependency Injection was designed to be non-invasive and allow for multiple components of the same type (a limitation in some type centric DI libraries), at the same time as allowing IDE code completion and refactoring. And also to avoid the use of "magic strings" (although unfortunately in Swift, selectors *are* strings).

**Proceeding from one controller to another:**

The assembly itself can be injected, so that our WeatherReportController can present a CitiesListController by calling `assembly.citiesListController`. We can also have a mixture of static and runtime dependencies using Typhoon's [runtime-arguments](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#injection-with-run-time-arguments), which saves the tedium of having to manually write your own factory for this.

**Storyboards:**

For story board segues, Typhoon property or [method dependencies can be injected as part of the segue](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Obtaining-Built-Components#typhoonstoryboard).

[image]

Typhoon works with Swift or Objective-C and is particularly popular in Australia, Japan and [Russia](http://mbltdev.ru/)

**Testing:**

Here's how to test view controller logic with story boards and dependency injection.

In the unit test you can inject your UIStoryboard subclass as "storyboard" property ( try setValue:forKey since it's read only property. Otherwise you can instantiate your viewController from your UIStoryboard subclass - another way to fill 'storyboard' property but much more verbose)
After replacing .storyboard property you can spy "instantiateViewControllerForStoryboardIdentifier" method and check that it's called with correct identifier.